# How can I find an element by attribute in a tag?

Tags: angular, protractor

Here I want to click this anchor tag using attribute `mattooltip="Edit project"` or `ng-reflect-message`:

```html
<a _ngcontent-htr-c655="" mat-menu-item="" mattooltip="Edit project"
    class="mat-focus-indicator mat-tooltip-trigger mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-message="Edit project"
    ng-reflect-router-link="94/241/edit" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"
    href="#/enso-business-setup/enso-manage-project/94/241/edit" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-94"
    cdk-describedby-host="">Edit
    <div matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-menu-ripple" ng-reflect-disabled="false"
        ng-reflect-trigger="https://dev-app.neoenso.com/#/">
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: in Angular you use a template reference variable and [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild). when you has the ElementRef, using `this.myelement.nativeElement.getAttribute('href')` you get the url, after this you can use [router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [sat-popover](https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover) in Angular.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ncstate-sat-popover-examples-v2nh5v

Answer (score 0):

99% of my cases I use either `by.xpath` or `by.css`. So don't overcomplicate it more than this. In this case css is the easiest way

For locating by tag do

```
let link = element(by.css('a')) // assuming there is only one a tag
// or
let link = $('a') // shorter way for finding elements in protractor
```

by attribute

```
let link = element(by.css('[mattooltip="Edit project"]'))
// or
let link = $('[mattooltip="Edit project"]') // shorter way for finding elements in protractor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically wants to use 2 locators with "OR" condition, in case where either 1st locator finds the element or 2nd locator, then you can also use COMMA separated selectors i.e.

```
const link_elem = element(by.css('[mattooltip="Edit project"], [ng-reflect-message="Edit project"]'));
```